# Всплывающие подсказки с задержкой. jquery.

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте.
Вот что я сделал: http://jsfiddle.net/Rknyz/
Но есть одна загвоздка, нужно чтобы при наведении на всплывающую подсказку она задерживалась, а при потере курсора исчезала.
Не подскажете как это сделать?

Comment: смотрите SetInterval

Answer (score 1):

Я бы изменил верстку так, чтобы "подсказка" стала частью блока, при наведении на который она появляется - это решит проблему с несвоевременным исчезанием. Это самый простой вариант решения.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var wind =$('<div id="show_block"><form><textarea></textarea><input type="submit"></form></div>');

    $('.button').hover(function(){
        var pos = $(this).offset();
         wind.appendTo('body')
          .css({'left' : pos.left, 'margin-top' : pos.top+10}).delay(1000)
          .slideToggle(400);

    });

 })​
```

От значения delay() меняется время задержки.

Comment: Это просто как пример, так как на вскидку, не идеал)

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.tipped{border-bottom:1px dashed;display:inline;position:relative}
.tipped .tip{background:#fff;border:1px solid #000;display:none;margin:-2px 0 0;padding:10px;position:absolute;top:100%}
</style>

Здравствуйте. Вот что я <div class="tipped">сделал<div class="tip">зря</div></div>: http://jsfiddle.net/Rknyz/ Но есть одна загвоздка, нужно чтобы при наведении на всплывающую подсказку она задерживалась, а при потере курсора исчезала. Не <div class="tipped">подскажете<form class="tip"><textarea cols="40"rows="4">Оставьте заявку</textarea><input type="submit" value="Отправить"></form></div> как это сделать?

<script>
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.tipped', function(){
    var t = this;
    t.a = setTimeout(function(){
        var tip = $(t).find('.tip');
        tip.css({left: ($(t).outerWidth() - tip.outerWidth())/2}).slideDown(200);
        t.a = false;
    }, 700);
}).on('mouseleave', '.tipped', function(){
    var t = this;
    if(t.a) clearTimeout(t.a);
    else{
        t.a = setTimeout(function(){
            $(t).find('.tip').slideUp(200);
        }, 300);
    }
});
</script>
```